# Git pull keeps asking for password even after correct one is inputted

Tags: php, git, ssh

All of a sudden this morning, our of no where, am I receiving all these problems with my SSH settings and I'm unable to push or pull to origin at all. Below, I will go into details what all I am experiencing right now.

**First error**:
`sma@US3FHIM0XQ86TJG: ~/Sites/LoremIpsum.com/sites/htdocs[develop]$ git pull
identity_sign: private key /Users/{{User}}/.ssh/id_rsa contents do not match public`

The public key (id_rsa.pub) has not been changed nor has the private key (id_rsa).

**Second error**:
`sma@US3FHIM0XQ86TJG: ~/Sites/LoremIpsum.com/sites/htdocs[develop]$ git pull
git@git.ccmgrid.com's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.`

Keeps telling me that it's permission denied, although the correct password is inputted and it just keeps looping for like 5 times.

**Things that I have checked**:

.git/config: *Checks out*
`[remote "origin"]
url = git@git.ccmgrid.com:corp/sites.LoremIpsum.com.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`

~/.ssh contains:
`- authorized_keys = Which has the public key inside
- id_rsa = which has the private key
- ir_rsa.pub = which has the public key`

Both my public keys on github (Origin) and Azure DevOps match the public key in id_rsa.pub.

Can someone help me? I'm unsure what else to try, I've tried ssh-add, tried hundreds of different commands and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: The first thing to do is to eliminate Git from the equations. Git never (never? well, not in this case for sure) asks for passwords: Git runs other things, and it's the other things that ask for passwords. So: run `ssh git@git.ccmgrid.com`, perhaps with `-vvv` to make it super-verbose as to what it's doing and/or with `-T` to force pty allocation, and debug from there.

Comment: If you're sure you haven't changed the private or public keys, `git.ccmgrid.com`'s server or database is the problem.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, went ahead and saved the headache and just got a new public and private key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ~/.ssh contains:
>
> - authorized_keys = Which has the public key inside

That... would not matter at all for a successful SSH connection: the public key needs to be in the `~git/.ssh/authorized` key of the remote side (the server: git.ccmgrid.com)

And if not, SSH will default back to asking the password of the remote server-side `git` account. Entering your own password would not work.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, went ahead and saved the headache and just got a new public and private key.